# Etymology of "Wertgegenstand"

Tags: etymology

I can't understand very well..

According to [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/wordformation/wertgegenstand:N:M), *Wertgegenstand* is composed of *Wert* (value), *gegen* (against) and *[Stand](https://www.wordreference.com/deen/Stand)* (state).

So does this mean something like "stand against value?" And what would be a better, "smoother" translation?

[image]

Comment: You should decompose the word stepwise: `Wertgegenstand=Wert+Gegenstand`. `Wert=value/worth` correct. But `Gegenstand` is difficult itself.

Comment: Gegenstand seems to mean a lot of things: http://it.bab.la/dizionario/tedesco-inglese/gegenstand

Comment: See here: http://dict.leo.org/itde/index_de.html#/search=gegenstand

Comment: I made the proffered definition more specific (less unclear), and wonder if the question can be re-opened in its current form.

Comment: @Toscho: Bei "Holztischintarsie" teilt man "Holztisch" und "Intarsie" - woher soll man vorab wissen, ob man schrittweise von vorne oder von hinten aufteilt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No problem.

*Stand* is just the noun of *stehen*.

A *Gegenstand* may be translated as an opposing thing.
The word was formed in the 18th century and called the thing standing in front of you. But it does not necessarily really be in front of you anymore.
Today you may use the word in a metaphorical sense, as an object or a deed may be the *Gegenstand* of your conversation.

As no one cares for such subtleties of language anymore you may be able to just translate it with an object or even a thing.

If something is called a Wertgegenstand it's -quite simple- a worthy object -> valuable article.

Hope got this now :)

To explain the left right info:
It's a neologism, which is made by a noun (Wert) and another noun (Gegenstand) and has no interfix* between them.

*(Dont know how popular this word is, but there are no letters between *Wert* and *Gegenstand*)

Comment: Thanks. Gegenstand and Wertgegenstand have synonims which are more used?

Comment: @Revious: There are similar words, but no synonyms. Zu *Gegenstand* fallen mir `Ding, Artikel, Objekt, Sache` ein, und im Kontext von "Unterhaltung" oder Diskussion auch `Thema`. For me, a "Gegenstand" is a thing that is small enough for me to handle and look at from all sides. A book, a telephone and similar things fit, a bicycle possibly, but not a car and certainly not a house, neither an animal.

Comment: @Reviuos: *Wertgegenstand* means a valuable item, like a ring, or a coin, or even a key that's not valuable in itself but for what it grants access to. "Bitte schließen Sie ihre Wertgegenstände in die Schließfächer ein" (Please lock your valuable items in the lockers) would be a typical sign at the entrace to a public swimming pool - obviously this includes wallet, car keys, mobile phone, and similar items that might get stolen easily and are valuable enough for a thief to be interested in. "Wertsache" is almost a synonym here.

Comment: Bitte benutze kein privates, fancy -Markup- sondern bediene Dich an den Knöpfen, die der Editor mitbringt (fett, kursiv).

Comment: @GuntramBlohmsupportsMonica "Ein Auto ist für mich ein reiner Gebrauchsgegenstand" habe ich häufig genug gehört, um Deinem Kommentar zu widersprechen.

Comment: DWDS dates "zuerst ‘Widerstand’ (16. Jh.), ‘Gegensatz’, auch ‘das Entgegenstehende’ (17. Jh.), dann (Ende 17. Jh.) Übersetzung von Objekt bzw. lat. obiectum in philosophischer Sprache".